# (Assembly) behavior of trying to load data into registers that cannot fit it?

Tags: assembly, x86, att

I am learning assembly right now, and was just wondering if anyone could clarify the behavior of trying to move data into a register that cannot fit it.

For example, suppose we had (on x86, AT&T syntax):

```
movl $0xff00abcd, %ax
```

Where %ax is the 16-bit subregister of %eax, what happens? Will the instruction fail entirely, or will %ax contain $0xff00?

Comment: By the way, this issue only exists at the assembly level. In x86 machine code, there is no way to even express "overloading" `ax` like that. So whatever happens, is not a property of how x86 processors work, but of how the assembler chooses to handle it.

Comment: It won't assemble because you specified `l` size with a 16-bit word-sized register.  Just try it!  (And look at disassembly).  If you fix that, you get `Warning: -16733235 shortened to 43981`.  (At least with GAS from GNU Binutils 2.35.1; `clang -c` doesn't warn.)

Comment: you cant make a processor do what it cant do.  And you cant fit more than x bits into an x bit register.  it will place the x bits defined by the instruction into the register.  There is no magic nor mystery with processors.  They are incredibly simple and dumb...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Such an instruction is *not encodeable*: there is simply no sequence of bytes of machine code that would tell the CPU to move the value `0xff00abcd` into `ax`.  (Why should the architecture designers have designated any sequence of bytes to tell the CPU to do this, when it's obviously impossible?).  So it is not possible to execute such an instruction, since it doesn't exist.

So what will your *assembler* do when asked to assemble an instruction that doesn't exist?  It should warn you, of course.  What it does next just depends on how your assembler was designed.  Some assemblers might just make this a fatal error and refuse to continue until you fix it.  Others might emit the machine code for some different instruction in hopes that it might be what you meant.

What gas apparently does, matching the way that overflow is handled in many other situations, is to truncate the high bits and emit the machine code for `movw $0xabcd, %ax`.  It wouldn't be a good idea to rely on this behavior, though.

Comment: Interestingly, `clang -c foo.s` fails to warn.  `as` from GNU Binutils *does* warn though, like I commented on other answers.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, that isn't the correct suffix for `mov`ing to a 16-bit register.`movl` means "`mov` to a longword/doubleword", so that would have to change to `movw` for "`mov` to a word" which is the size of the `ax` register. With that out of the way, a debugger is the easiest way to check such behavior. Assuming you're using GAS from the AT&T syntax, this can be checked with this simple program:

```
.text
    .globl main
main:
    movw $0xff00abcd, %ax
    # Then exit the program
```

GAS is likely to complain about this: for me, it produced this warning:

```
test.S: Assembler messages:
test.S:4: Warning: -16733235 shortened to 43981
```

If I put a breakpoint right after that `movw` instruction, I can see that `%ax` holds `0xabcd`, so the low 16 bits. This may not be a guarantee for you too though, maybe there could be some other factors, one of these being that, as harold has noted, this is something the assembler will have to handle, not the processor. So if you *aren't* using GAS, or perhaps even if you are, you may not experience the same behavior as I am experiencing.

Comment: You should also mention that GAS warns `Warning: -16733235 shortened to 43981`, unless older GAS doesn't do that?  Interestingly, `clang -c foo.s` *doesn't* warn.

Comment: @PeterCordes you're right, it does. I ran this through an online x64 assembler because I generally write most of my code on a virtual machine, and I didn't want to turn that on. I guess the online assembler didn't produce the warning. I just tested it on the VM right now and it did, though. I'll try to be warier of this next time, thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

The instruction fail entirely, if you compile you will get:

```
warning: word data exceeds bounds [-w+number-overflow]
```

So you will first have to move your data to `eax` register, and then `ax` will contain the lower 16-bits of `eax`, so `ax` will be equal to `0xabcd`

Comment: That's a NASM warning; this question is about a different assembler.  (Which also warns: `Warning: -16733235 shortened to 43981`)